# "Yet", "Still", "Also" to say a further possibility

Tags: word-choice

I wrote:

> By default, any user-created ruleset is derived from a master ruleset, which includes the basic heuristic rules to cover the common tasks required by the extraction algorithm. However, it is **[yet / still / also]?** possible to override each rule in a derived ruleset.

When you want to say another option still exits, what is common? yet or still or also?

However, in my sentence, I think I should use "also" because I am saying that a user is not required to be bound to the rules in the master ruleset?!

Comment: *yet* is not a good choice. Still or also look fine in this context.

Comment: _also_ doesn't have a clear referent. It leaves me wondering "In addition to what?"  What else is "possible"? What else can you "override"?  So I'd favor _still_  (meaning _nevertheless/ despite whatever was just said_).

Comment: @BrianHitchcock You can leave some rules as they are defined in the master ruleset or restrict them (make them specific) in a derived ruleset. Now, can "also" be used?

Comment: In your sentence, I believe that nothing is good and arguably the best: *However, it is possible to override ...* or *However, the user can override ...*

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're trying to say would be more readily understood by 'flagging' the change of direction, either with something like *although* at the beginning or by uniting the two sentences with a semicolon:

> Although every user-created ruleset is derived from a master ruleset [...], it is possible for the user-created ruleset to override any rule inherited from the master ruleset.
>
> By default, any user-created ruleset is derived from a master ruleset [...]; but it is possible for the user-created ruleset to override any rule inherited from the master ruleset.

Note that I've rewritten your second proposition, where it's not entirely clear which rules are overridden.

Comment: Thank you, however I feel I can even omit "however" and "but" and just say "*By default, any user-created ..... It is still possible for the user-created ruleset to overrride any rule inherited ...*". I am reporting two facts, the main fact and an option. like you say "You can travel by this airline on Monday. It is still possible for you to go by train if you're afraid of flight"